# windows batch script to consider path of executable with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have windows batch script `calculate.bat` like below:

```
@echo on

REM check if the user has provided the expected number of arguments
if "%~2"=="" (
  echo Usage: %0 ^<directory location of dll files^> ^<directory location of calculate executable^>
  exit /b 1
)

set "search_dir=%~1"
set "calc_path=%~2"

cd  C:\tmp\xyz.d\

if exist checksum_file (
  del checksum_file
)

set "calc_exe=%calc_path%\calc.exe"


REM iterate over all .dll files in the search directory
for %%I in ("%search_dir%\*.dll") do (

REM #working with calc_exe path without spaces,but does not work with path having spaces
for /F %%A in ('%calc_exe% "%%I"') do echo %%I %%A >> checksum_file

)
```

Here it works if the path of second argument passed is not having spaces `"C:\Working\test\bin"`.
For example:
`calculate.bat "C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64" "C:\Working\test\bin"`

But if I pass the path of second argument with spaces `"C:\Program Files\test\bin"`:
For example:
 `calculate.bat "C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64" "C:\Working\test\bin"`
It does not work and gives error as below:

```
 for /F %A in ('C:\Program Files\test\bin\calc.exe "C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64\sample.dll"') do echo C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64\sample.dll %A  1>>checksum_file
)
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here its considering path till first occurrence of space.
I tried putting `"%calc_exe%"` still getting same error:

```
for /F %%A in ('"%calc_exe%" "%%I"') do echo %%I %%A >> checksum_file
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is because the `for /F` loop in the batch script treats space-separated values as separate tokens. So, when you pass a path with spaces (`C:\Program Files\test\bin`), it considers `C:\Program` and `Files\test\bin` as two tokens and tries to execute them (one after the other), resulting in the error you see.

```
@echo on

REM check if the user has provided the expected number of arguments
if "%~2"=="" (
  echo Usage: %0 ^<directory location of dll files^> ^<directory location of calculate executable^>
  exit /b 1
)

set "search_dir=%~1"
set "calc_path=%~2"

cd C:\tmp\xyz.d\

if exist checksum_file (
  del checksum_file
)

set "calc_exe=%calc_path%\calc.exe"

REM iterate over all .dll files in the search directory
for %%I in ("%search_dir%\*.dll") do (

  REM #working with calc_exe path with spaces
  for /F %%A in ('"%calc_exe%" "%%I"') do echo %%I %%A >> checksum_file

)
```

By enclosing `%calc_exe%` within double quotes in the for /F loop, the entire path will be treated as a single token, and the script will work correctly with paths that have spaces.

Now, you can execute the batch script like this:

```
calculate.bat "C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64" "C:\Working\test\bin"
```

Comment: Hi @amNotthatHelpfull, this was already tried, there also I am getting error as below:

```
for /F %A in ('"C:\Program Files\test\bin\calc.exe" "C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64\sample.dll"') do echo C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64\sample.dll %A  1>>checksum_file
)
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Sorry Amy, I don't know how to post code on replies but here is the code in Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/5TmJMWBS

Comment: with suggestion of usebackq I am still getting error:
for /F "usebackq" %A in (`"C:\Program Files\BMC Software\Patrol3\bin\csum.exe" "C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64\sample.dll"`) do echo C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64\sample.dll %A  1>>checksum_file )
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: why `for /f`? (btw, you'd also need `"delims="`)? `for %A in ("C:\Program Files\BMC Software\Patrol3\bin\csum.exe" "C:\Program Files\test\Windows-x86-64\sample.dll") do ...